# Curl to httplib

Tags: python

I am able to access a webservice by using curl as given below

`curl -k -u "admin:password" "https://10.184.39.12:8080/mypage/managed/user?_query=query-all"`

I want to access it by python code. I can use httplib.

```
connection.request("GET",url,params,headers)
```

1. Are the options `-k`, `-u "admin:password"` are headers.
2. If so how could I write in code as headers?

Please help.

Comment: `-k` isn’t a header; and `-u` just sets up [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your username and password as `base64` and add that to the headers. Something like this:

```
import base64
import string
import httplib
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
webservice = httplib.HTTP(host)
webservice.putheader("Authorization", "Basic %s" % auth)
# Add other headers etc
```

There's more information on this blog post: http://mozgovipc.blogspot.nl/2012/06/python-http-basic-authentication-with.html